# How to pass from Eclipse 32 bits to 64 bits?

Tags: eclipse, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I am using a 32 bits Eclipse and I want to migrate to a 64 bits versions of it with ALL my configuration and plugins, so that my migration would be invisible.

All my attempts so far have shown some problems : plugins not working, but that are shown as installed, lost of workspace configuration...
I try to migrate from Eclipse Oxygen (2018-03) 32bits to Eclipse Oxygen (2018-03) 64bits.

I tried to duplicate my current "eclipse" folder and my "workspace" folder, then to unzip the 64bits Eclipse into the duplicate of my Eclipse, but it doesn't work, as some of my plugins are gone...

Somebody has done it before ? I can't find any help on the web.

Comment: Plug-ins can contain code which is 32bit only (or 64bit only, or for a particular operating system). For any plug-ins like that you will have to obtain the 64bit version.

Comment: Do not mix a 32-bit installation with a 64-bit installation. Install the 64-bit version separately, import the additional plug-ins from the 32-bit installation into the 64-bit installation via _File > Import...: Install > From Existing Installation_ and switch to your old workspace without moving it to a different location. The current version is Eclipse 2018-12 and it is not recommended to use an outdated version.

Comment: Thank you @howlger : this seems to be the best thing to do, but how do I manage the case of plugins like [Mylyn Wikitext](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mylyn-wikitext) that are not available for 2018-12 ?

Comment: @pierreonthenet I guess the Wikitext Marketplace entry is outdated because the Markdown editor provided by Wikitext is still in 2018-12. As long as the plug-ins do not contain 32-bit code, you can install it from your old installation. You can also use an update site created for a previous release (there are only rar cases where a plugin uses internal code from the platform or other plug-ins that has changed). If installing via Marketplace does not work, go to the project web site to find an update site URL that can be used in _Help > Install New Software..._.